# Scala dynamic return type based on input type

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

Ok so I don't know what's bugging in this code:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
trait Key extends Product
case class SomeKey(a: Int, b: String) extends Key
case class SomeOtherKey(a: Int, b: String, c:Boolean) extends Key

trait MyTrait[T <: Key] {
  def someField: Int
  def someFunc(implicit tTypeTag: TypeTag[T]): Map[T, Int] = {
    typeOf(tTypeTag) match {
      case t if t =:= typeOf[SomeKey] => Map(SomeKey(1,"2") -> 1)
      case t if t =:= typeOf[SomeOtherKey] => Map(SomeOtherKey(1,"2",true) -> 2)
    }
  }
}
```

I want (the example has been oversimplified) to be able to return a `Map[SomeKey, Int]` if `someFunc` is called from a case class extending `MyTrait[SomeKey]`. And return a `Map[SomeOtherKey, Int]` from a `MyTrait[SomeOtherKey]`

```
case class MyClass(val s: Int) extends MyTrait[SomeKey] {
  override def someField = s
}
```

Here a new instance of `MyClass` should return a `Map[SomeKey, Int]` when calling `someFunc`.

But it does not even compile, compiler complaining for each line of the pattern match:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (Playground.this.SomeKey, Int)
 required: (T, Int)
```

or

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (Playground.this.SomeOtherKey, Int)
 required: (T, Int)
```

Comment: Can you expand on what information you need to know about the specific kind of key? Also, it is necessary that the method has to be defined in the same trait? Or may it be added as an extension method?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using type classes and implicits.

```scala
trait Key extends Product
case class SomeKey(a: Int, b: String) extends Key
case class SomeOtherKey(a: Int, b: String, c:Boolean) extends Key

trait TypeClass[T] {
  def someFunc: Map[T, Int]
}
object TypeClass {
  implicit def forSomeKey: TypeClass[SomeKey] = new TypeClass[SomeKey] {
    override def someFunc: Map[SomeKey, Int] = Map(SomeKey(1, "2") -> 1)
  }
  implicit def forSomeOtherKey: TypeClass[SomeOtherKey] = new TypeClass[SomeOtherKey] {
    override def someFunc: Map[SomeOtherKey, Int] = Map(SomeOtherKey(1, "2", true) -> 1)
  }
}

trait MyTrait[T <: Key] {
  def someField: Int
  def someFunc(implicit tc: TypeClass[T]): Map[T, Int] = tc.someFunc
}
```

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I independently came up with an identical answer and got beat to posting by seconds. Though I would call `TypeClass` something more descriptive e.g. `IntMapProvider` or something.

Comment: @JoeK That would be the third identical answer then! Mario Galic's answer is more fleshed out - no point polishing this now.

Answer (score 3):

`TypeTag` will carry over type information to **runtime** however return-type of a method is **compile-time** construct, hence the compiler error. Instead consider typeclass solution via extension method <sup>(yet again hijacked from Luis' suggestion)</sup>

```
sealed trait Key
final case class SomeKey(a: Int, b: String) extends Key
final case class SomeOtherKey(a: Int, b: String, c: Boolean) extends Key

trait MyTrait[T <: Key]

trait KeyFactory[T <: Key] {
  def someFunc(): Map[T, Int]
}

object KeyFactory {
  def someFunc[T <: Key](implicit ev: KeyFactory[T]) = ev.someFunc
  implicit val someKeyFoo: KeyFactory[SomeKey] = () => Map(SomeKey(1,"2") -> 1)
  implicit val someOtherKey: KeyFactory[SomeOtherKey] = () => Map(SomeOtherKey(1,"2", true) -> 2)
}

implicit final class MyTraitKeyFactory[T <: Key : KeyFactory](private val v: MyTrait[T]) {
  def someFunc(): Map[T, Int] = implicitly[KeyFactory[T]].someFunc()
}

case class MyClass(s: Int) extends MyTrait[SomeKey]
case class MyOtherClass(s: Int) extends MyTrait[SomeOtherKey]


MyOtherClass(42).someFunc()
MyClass(11).someFunc()
```

which outputs

```
res0: Map[SomeOtherKey,Int] = Map(SomeOtherKey(1,2,true) -> 2)
res1: Map[SomeKey,Int] = Map(SomeKey(1,2) -> 1)
```